# How to get help on texlive installed from distro repository?

Tags: packages, texlive, best-practices

I am quite a newbie in TeX community. Previously, I had a TexLive installation from a DVD, and It did work pretty good. Now, I am on another machine with disk space constraint. So I chose to stay with the distro-based Texlive, I'm running fedora 22.

```
texlive.x86_64  4:2014-8.20140525_r34255.fc22   @System
```

What I really miss is **tlmgr**, I used it mainly to find package matching a specific word.

My question is *How do you get help on Texlive? How do you know which packages match your need when you want to customize your document?*

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! On some Linux distributions the repository version is outdated (yours seems to be - I could be horribly wrong here - TeXLive 2014, the current version is 2015), so I would advocate a vanilla install ([here for Debian/Ubuntu](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/1092/35864)). But if you can't do that you can easily google for a suitable package (assuming you have internet access). See also http://forums.fedoraforum.org/showthread.php?t=260451.

Comment: If you install from TUG (the "vanilla install") you can choose to customize the collection as small as you like. If you leave out the documentation, editors, and package collections you know you are unlikely to use, you can get a very small minimal installation. And since you have `tlmgr` you can always add things back in later.

Comment: Thanks for your answers but I would really like to hear your answers on: _How do you get help on Texlive? How do you know which packages match your need when you want to customize your document?_